# Insert DOM elements in text

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have two div elements. The div on the left side contains text and the div on the right side contains "images", "video" and "audio". I'd like to be able to drag (btw. and clone) elements from div on the right side to div on the left side. I used sortable from JQueryUI:

```
$("#divRight").sortable({
    connectWith: ".divLeft",
    forcePlaceholderSize: false,
    opacity: 0.5,
    revert: true,
    cursor: "move",
    helper: function(e, li) {
        copyHelper = li.clone().insertAfter(li);
        return li.clone();
    },
    stop: function() {
        copyHelper && copyHelper.remove();
    }
});
$(".divLeft").sortable({
    opacity: 0.5,
    //  revert: true,
    cursor: "move",
    receive: function(e, ui) {
        copyHelper = null;
    }
});
```

but i can't put elements into "< p >"

example:
http://jsfiddle.net/eD8d6/1/

Comment: Can you toss what you're doing into a jsfiddle? We don't have much to go on.  Also, you might be able to get away with just using draggable

Comment: please create fiddle !

Comment: I don't think sortable works with `<p>` elements, because it has no way of finding position of text where  you're dropping something, flowing the text around it accordingly, etc...